# Should the Spring Equinox be New Year's Day?

Tags: society, culture, time-keeping

Time and time again, the history of the calendar is so complicated because of how arbitrary the system is.  Before Julius Caesar, a whole year in the Roman calendar is ten months.  The Chinese calendar is so tied with the moon that the new year varies between late January and February.

But in nature, the new year starts with the spring equinox, where the hardships of winter are over for the year and migrants can come back to have their young.

Is it feasible for the human calendar to make the spring equinox New Year's Day as well?  If no, then why not?

Comment: Consider: **what *is* New Year?** What's so special about that one revolution of the Earth around its axis, as opposed to the approximately 364 others that also happen during the same sidereal year?

Comment: Hello John, is this a worldbuilding question? That is, are you building a **fictional** world where this matters? If so, can you expand your question?

Comment: This screams "opinion-based" to me.

Comment: I wouldn't call it opinion based, the answer is simply "yes". However it's not strictly world building.

Comment: @fi12 I second that. Questions that use the word "should" generally do because it is an open invitation for anyone with an opinion on what should happen. **Could a culture make the start of spring their "new year"** would be a better question.

Comment: I edited the question. If I messed anything up, feel free to roll back or improve the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Year

> During the Middle Ages in western Europe, while the Julian calendar was still in use, authorities moved New Year's Day variously, depending upon locale, to one of several other days, among them: 1 March, 25 March, Easter, 1 September, and 25 December. These New Year's Day changes generally reverted to using January 1 before or during the various local adoptions of the Gregorian calendar, beginning in 1582. The change from March 25 – Lady Day, one of the four quarter days – to January 1 took place in Scotland in 1600, before the ascension of James VI of Scotland to the throne of England in 1603 and well before the formation of the Kingdom of Great Britain in 1707. In England and Wales (and in all British dominions, including Britain's American colonies), 1751 began on March 25 and lasted 282 days, and 1752 began on January 1.[2] For more information about the changeover from the Julian calendar to the Gregorian calendar and the effect on the dating of historical events etc., see Old Style and New Style dates.

As you can see from this article, you can in practice put the new year whenever you like. Different calendars still have it in different places, some calendars, like the Jewish calendar, actually have a selection of new years for historic reasons, including one at the start of spring, one in the autumn, and another in approximately late January just for trees.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to define seasons and, most importantly, their effects are roughly inverse on the opposite hemisphere: Northern summer = Southern winter. I will use the terms applicable to the Northern hemisphere below, because English originates there.

### Possible definitions of “spring”

The OP seems to be assuming [four seasons of similar lengths](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:4-season_calendar) running from solstice to equinox and vice versa. That would be [*astronomical* seasons](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Astronomic_year_start). 
They can be partitioned by the 12 Western *astrological* zodiac signs: Aries ♈ + Taurus ♉ + Gemini ♊ = spring, Cancer ♋ + Leo ♌ + Virgo ♍ = summer, Libra ♎ + Scorpio ♏ + Sagittarius ♐ = autumn/fall, Capricorn ♑ + Aquarius ♒ + Pisces ♓ = winter. So Northern spring runs from ca. 21 March till 20 June (inclusive).

A competing, but equally valid, astrological definition would be to have equinoxes and solstices at the center and not the edge of seasons, because that way, the first and last day of a season would have about equal amounts of daylight and the extreme (maximum or minimum) would be in the middle. Northern spring would then run from ca. 5 February to 5 May.
One could combine both astronomical variants to get an [eight-“month” calendar](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Octant_Calendar).

Since the meteorological (hence agricultural) effects of more (or less) sunlight lag a bit behind, it can make sense to postpone the start and end a bit. *Meteorological* spring in Europe, for instance, runs from 1 March to 31 May, as all such seasons consist of three complete months.

In many places, however, especially closer to the equator, agricultural seasons (if any) are not linked to solar turning points at all. If I remember correctly, there were just 3 seasons in ancient Greece, for example, whereas Romans considered 4. Monsoon or flooding (e.g. in case of Egypt) and dry seasons are usually very important and (seemingly) detached from the astronomical seasons.

In the modern *business* world, [weeks](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Leap_week_calendar) are often more important than months and [*quarters*](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Equal-quarter_calendars) are more important than seasons, although they can be designed to match. A quarter-year is formed either of 3 months or of 13 weeks. The ones best matching Northern spring would be 1 April through 31 July and Monday 4 April through Sunday 3 July 2016 or [ISO week](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/ISO_week_date) 14 through 26 – in some other years it would be weeks 13–25.

One may wish to have a season consist of an integer amount of full *weeks*, which some consider to start on Monday, others on Sunday or Saturday. Using one of the astronomical definitions above, this would shift the beginning of seasons by up to ±3 days. Northern spring with roughly equinox start could then run from Monday 21 March to Sunday 19 June in 2016 or week 12 through 24 – in some other years it would be weeks 11–23.

Some would even bring Moon into the game, as the Christian [Computus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus) does (or tries to do): “In principle, Easter falls on the Sunday following the full moon that follows the northern spring equinox (the paschal full moon).” In 2016, this results in a date of 27 March for the Catholic and most other Western churches using the Gregorian calendar and 1 May for the (Eastern) Orthodox churches using the Julian calendar – both could be valid starts of spring and the year and so could be Carnival 7 weeks earlier. (By the way, talks have recently begun again to unify the dates.)

Instead of the Sunday after the paschal full moon, that *lunar* phase or a new moon could be used directly as start of the season consisting of 3 or 4 [lunations](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Lunar_calendars) (of 29 or 30 days each). In the Middle and Far East, lunar calendars are still popular after all.

The school and *academic* years in many places start in September (or October), which would make a 3-month spring trimester run from March to June (or April to July or even January to March).

### Conclusion

In conclusion, it may make sense to have a culture start the year on its definition of the beginning of spring (i.e. “planting season”), but such a calendar may never apply on a global scale (unless it’s for a planet with habitable, farmable landmass restricted to one hemisphere).

Answer (score 1):

### Spring is already the start of year in Persian culture!

[**Jalali calendar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jalali_calendar) is already in use in Iran and the first day of year is the first astronomical day of spring (with a good precision) called *nowruz* and it is in use since 1079, made by [Khayyam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_Khayyam) (whom you might have heard his name for his famous poets).

Actually as a festival in Iran all the family gathers around and waits for the time astronomers have calculated to be the exact time of starting point for the spring and then celebrates the newyear!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could. People have had many different New Year's days over the course of history. I'm sure you could make a logical argument for many possible dates. Your vernal equinox argument is plausible. By the same reasoning one could say the day after the winter equinox, because that's when the Sun starts shining longer and brighter and so the world begins "coming back to life". I've never heard an argument for the anniversary of the day the world was created, but that seems like an obvious one to me. (Maybe because no one's sure when that was?) The day that your nation became independent is another obvious one, though of course that has the problem that it would be different for every country. How about finding the last day when all the planets in the Solar System were in conjunction, and go from the anniversary of that?

I'm sure one could come up with many ideas that have logical merit. Does it matter? Who cares? I think it's more important that we all use the same New Years Day then what day it is.